# Loop invariant for pivot sort

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out if the algorithm is correct using loop invariants (Using the initialization, maintenance and termination method.) as well as getting the assertion and post-condition for it. I have something but I'm unsure if its the correct way of approaching it as there is uncertainty about the output of one of the values at any point in the algorithm (mid depends on if arr[sweep]

```
int partition(int arr[], int first, int last) {
    int mid = first;
    int pivot = arr[first];
     for (int sweep = first+1; sweep <= last; sweep++) {
        // Assertion: . . .
        if (arr[sweep] < pivot) {
            int tmp = arr[sweep];
            arr[sweep] = arr[mid+1];
            arr[mid+1] = tmp;
            mid++;
        }
    }   
    // Post: . . .
     arr[first] = arr[mid];
     arr[mid] = pivot;
    return mid;
}
```

I've managed to come up with this:

I:

First=0

Last=Length-1

Mid=0

M:

At the start of the loop, where i is now i + 1

First=0

Last=Length-1

Sweep = first + 2

Mid= i + (first)= i (where i's value depends on if arr[sweep]

Sweep= Last+1

Mid = (last+1)+ (first) = (last + 1)+ (0 ) = Last + 1 (if all values were arr[sweep]

//Assertion: Before every loop mid= first + i where i is how many times arr[sweep]

//post-condition: arr[first..mid-1] will be less than arr[mid], 
arr[mid+1...last] > arr[mid]. Sweep = last + 1.

I'm new to loop invariants, I hope i'm doing this correctly. Any advice would be immensely helpful. :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: If the algorithm is correct.

Comment: I imagine the statement is something along the lines of: The procedure `partition` takes an array `arr` of `n>0` integers two indices, `0 <= first < last < n`, and returns an index `mid` such that `arr[i] < arr[mid]` for all `0 <= i < mid` and `arr[j] >= arr[mid]` for all `mid < j < n`.